# Using jquery remove style tag from html page

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there any way to remove a `<style>` tag from the page using jquery?
and i need to remove particular style tag.

Thanks.

Comment: `$('style').remove() ;` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('style').detach();
//        or
 $('style').remove();

});
```

reference **[.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)** and **[.detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)**

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove a specific style tag, you can add a class (or id) to it and then use remove() to remove that class. I have tested it and it works. I am not sure this should be allowed, but if you have no other options...

**HTML**

```
<style class="style-tag">
    p {
       color: #000;
    }
</style>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('.style-tag').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('style').remove() ;

});
```

Comment: Is there any way to remoev specify style element tag,thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

try `remove`
try this

```
$('style').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove a particular style tag, you'd need to assign it an id, like this:

```
<style id="someid">.elem{display:none;}</style>
```

After that use jQuery's remove function to get rid of it, like this:

```
$('style#someid').remove();
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to remove style tag from specific  class or id ,then you can just mention their class or id name. Like this:

**html**:

```
<style>
.menu { display: none; }
</style>
```

**jquery**:

```
$('.menu style').remove();
```