# Remove styles from internal style sheet using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
   .containerTitle {
     background-color:silver;
     text-align:center;
     font-family:'Segoe UI';
     font-size:18px;
     font-weight:bold;
     height:30px;
   }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="a"/>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I remove the styles applied to `.containerTitle` using jQuery?

Comment: You can't, it's a CSS rule, not an element on your page.

Comment: But you can remove that class form the elements it is applied to.

Comment: why do you want to remove  .containerTitle style?

Comment: because i will append that style dynamically based on input

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19627767/4028085

Comment: CSS is not part of the DOM, since it only affect the design. This cause the JavaScript not to be able to alter Style Sheet itself, but the design attributes. If you want to remove this CSS property, your logic is not good and you should renew it.

Comment: @Broxzier: *"You can't..."* [Yes, you can](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSStyleSheet-deleteRule).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's using regular JavaScript though, not jQuery, and OP states he wants to do it with jQuery.

Comment: @Broxzier: Splitting hairs, people frequently think they need jQuery for things they don't need jQuery for. And playing devil's advocate, you *could* use jQuery for parts of it (like looping through the list of stylesheets and list of rules). :-) (And pro forma: jQuery ***is*** regular JavaScript. Unless you're using CoffeeScript or TypeScript or Dart with it...)

Answer (score 5):

A couple of options:

If you can remove the entire *stylesheet* (by removing the `style` or `link` element), that will remove all rules defined by that stylesheet.

**Live Example**:

```js
$("input").on("click", function() {
  $("style").remove(); // Your selector would be more specific, presumably
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
.green {
  color: green;
}
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="red">red</div>
<div class="green">green</div>
<div class="blue">blue</div>
<input type="button" value="Click to remove the stylesheet">
```

Alternately, if you need to just remove **one** rule, you can, but it's a pain: You look through the [`styleSheets` collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets) to find the [stylesheet object for it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet), then find the relevant rule in the style sheet's `cssRules` list (called just `rules` on older IE), probably by looking at each [`CSSStyleRule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleRule)'s `selectorText` property, then call [`deleteRule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/deleteRule) to delete it.

```
// Loop through the stylesheets...
$.each(document.styleSheets, function(_, sheet) {
  // Loop through the rules...
  var keepGoing = true;
  $.each(sheet.cssRules || sheet.rules, function(index, rule) {
    // Is this the rule we want to delete?
    if (rule.selectorText === ".containerTitle") {
      // Yes, do it and stop looping
      sheet.deleteRule(index);
      return keepGoing = false;
    }
  });
  return keepGoing;
});
```

**Live Example** *(see comments)*:

```js
$("input").on("click", function() {
  // Loop through the stylesheets...
  $.each(document.styleSheets, function(_, sheet) {
    // Loop through the rules...
    var keepGoing = true;
    $.each(sheet.cssRules || sheet.rules, function(index, rule) {
      // Is this the rule we want to delete?
      if (rule.selectorText === ".green") {
        // Yes, do it and stop looping
        sheet.deleteRule(index);
        return keepGoing = false;
      }
    });
    return keepGoing;
  });
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
.green {
  color: green;
}
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="red">red</div>
<div class="green">green</div>
<div class="blue">blue</div>
<input type="button" value="Click to remove the green rule">
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Is `sheet.cssRules || sheet.rules` a compatibility fix? For which browser?

Comment: @papirtiger: Thanks. That's for older IE (I mention it buried in the the middle of a paragraph above).

Answer (score 0):

Personally if I was going to do something like this, I might put my css in a body element that can be easily replaced/removed.  http://jsfiddle.net/oqno5643/  Changed to set with html() rather than append() to remove previous values: http://jsfiddle.net/oqno5643/1/

HTML

```
<div id="test">Test text</div>
<input type="button" id="changer" value="Change to Blue">
<span id="styleContainer"></span>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#styleContainer').html('<style>#test{ color: red; }</style>');

    $('#changer').on('click', function() {
        $('#styleContainer').html('<style>#test{ color: blue; }</style>');
    });
});
```

Sorry, meant to do the html() instead of append() but forgot in my quick demo.

Comment: If he can edit the HTML why not just get rid of the offending style tag?

Answer (score -3):

You can't remove the style itself but you can remove it from any element it applies to.

`$('.containerTitle').removeClass('containerTitle');`

Comment: How this question is so controversial I'll never know. Poor guy probably inherited this code, didn't word his question properly, and just needs some help.